# If statement with OR condition not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have no JS or other language background. I have learned everything in the code for this particular problem so bear with me if things aren't clean and clever. I have done a lot of searching before resulting to asking here, so hopefully ALMOST everything is accounted for.

I have a conditional statement I just CANNOT get to run correctly. (entire code for context at the bottom)

```
            if (pyramid < 1 || pyramid > 8) {
                var dennis = document.getElementById("dennis");
                var showdennis = "#ahahah{display: block}";
                dennis.appendChild(document.createTextNode(showdennis));
                document.getElementById("giza").innerHTML = "";
                return;
            }
```

I am most concerned with (pyramid < 1 || pyramid > 8) but if you can help me account for an input value of zero (due to complexities with 0 being false-y), bonus points.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <style id="dennis">
    #ahahah {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Text Box Input and Output</h1>
  <form action="">
    <fieldset>
      <label>write how tall </label>
      <input type="number" id="numberin" min="" max="" step="1" />
      <input type="button" value="Make the Pyramid" onclick="makepyramid()" />
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function makepyramid() {
      var numberin = document.getElementById("numberin");

      var pyramid = numberin.value;
      var spaceincrement = numberin.value;
      var octoincrement = numberin.value;
      var spaces;
      var octothorps;
      var bringittogether = "";


      //WHY YOU NO WORK?! I'd like to make 0 work as well but I am more concerned with the range first.
      //first if statement is the ideal, second is bare minimum.
      //if (pyramid === null || pyramid < 1 || pyramid > 8) {
      //if (pyramid < 1 || pyramid > 8) {
      //Put in this if statement to show what SHOULD happen
        if (pyramid > 8) {
        var dennis = document.getElementById("dennis");
        var showdennis = "#ahahah{display: block}";
        dennis.appendChild(document.createTextNode(showdennis));
        document.getElementById("giza").innerHTML = "";
        return;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("ahahah").innerHTML = "";

        //decide how many lines to make
        for (var a = 0; a < pyramid; a++) {

          //number of spaces loop
          for (var b = 1, spaces = ""; b < spaceincrement; b++) {
            spaces += "_";
          }

          //number of octothorps in one line loop
          for (var c = pyramid, octothorps = ""; c >= octoincrement; c--) {
            octothorps += "#";
          }

          //print spaces, hashes, 2 spaces, start new line
          bringittogether += spaces + octothorps + "__" + octothorps + "<br/>";
          document.getElementById("giza").innerHTML = bringittogether;
          //increment to change next line's number of spaces (one less) and octothorps (one more)
          spaceincrement = [spaceincrement - 1];
          octoincrement = [octoincrement - 1];
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
  <hr />
  <div id="giza"></div>

  <div id="ahahah">
    <p><img src="https://i.imgur.com/1A8Zgnh.gif" /> You must select a number between 1 and 8
    </p>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are errors reported? Does *anything* happen?

Comment: @Pointy: Run the code snippet.

Comment: If you want to include zero as part of the if logic and have do the same as if the pyramid was less than 1 or greater than 8. Compare it with 0 instead of null. Otherwise i'd asking the same as "What exactly is the problem"

Comment: I'm assuming you want to display the gif if an invalid number is entered. Add this in the `if` block: `document.getElementById("ahahah").style.display = 'block'` I'm not sure why you are trying to access a `style` element.

Comment: Note that the validation works properly *until* you enter a valid value.

Comment: I assume the problem is `#ahahah` is not showing when given a wrong input. I must say, you chose a very complicated and unconventional way to do this. I don't quite understand why it doesn't work, but I'm not surprised.

Comment: @Pointy I changed it so you can see now if you enter a number above 8

Comment: @PedroLima the complicated and unconventional-ness comes from a lack of education and experience I'm sure. I'm open to alternate solultions, but I don't understand why my isn't working.

Comment: `if (pyramid === null || pyramid < 1 || pyramid > 8) {` doesn't make a lot of sense, since the `value` of an `HTMLInputElement` is never null; it's always a string (the empty string until set).

Comment: @Chief I have tried that (and variations of that), but first I am concerned with getting the range to work, which it does not:(

Comment: `if (pyramid < 1 || pyramid > 8) { document.getElementById("ahahah").style.display = 'block'; document.getElementById("giza").innerHTML = ""; } else { document.getElementById("ahahah").style.display = 'none'; // rest of the else block }` Here's a fiddle: **https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/25pu7h3L/**

Comment: Could `Number(numberin.value)` help instead of `numberin.value`?

Comment: @adiga this works THANK YOU. I don't understand why mine doesn't work still, but I will take what I can get!

Comment: You are trying to get the `style` element with the `id="dennis"`. Not sure why. You just need to change the `style.display` of `ahahah` element to `'block'` or '`none'` based on whether the value is valid or not.

Comment: @adiga Could you make your comment an answer so it's clear for anybody who happens upon this later? (New to stack overflow and not sure if I can do anything about doing that on my end)